# Looping Numeric ID for days 1-7, oracle APEX

Tags: sql, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have a table that identifies each day of the week with a number.

```
CREATE TABLE days_schedule (
days_schedule_id INT,
schedule_id INT,
day_id INT);

INSERT INTO TABLE days_schedule
VALUES (1001, 1007, 1);

INSERT INTO TABLE days_schedule
(1002, 1008, 2); ...
```

In another table, containing shipments, there is a column labelled AVAILABLE DAY which will have a number representing how many days after receiving a shipment that a product is available. For instance, if it says 14 days with an initial day of Monday (1), then it will be available on a Sunday (7), 14 days later. For now, I have used:

```
SELECT ...,
CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(
sd.day_id + sch.available_day, ' ('
), sch.available_day
), ')'
) as 'Available Day'
FROM schedule sch
INNER JOIN days_schedule sd
ON (sch.schedule_id = sd.schedule_id)
```

The issue I'm experiencing is that just adding the values of the two columns will simply provide a sum (15 in the above example).

How can I add the values and force the count to reset to 1 when it goes above 7.

Comment: Hint : use `mod(column,7)`

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a lot simpler and clearer:

```
mod(sd.day_id - 1 + sch.available_day, 7) + 1
   || ' (' || sch.available_day || ')' as "Available Day"
```

Comment: Thanks, also, I just ran into the problem of the code counting 0, I tried adding <>0 oustide it but it says "missing right parenthesis"

Comment: try something like `mod(sd.day_id - 1 + sch.available_day, 7) + 1`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by using
    `mod(sd.day_id + sch.available_day, 7)`
within the `CONCAT`